# How to separate words in an array list item?

Tags: java, android

I have any array list with two items, each having 3 words: a username, points, and high score (Example: ryan 120 medium). I want to be able to split these words from the array list item and display each word into a text view within android studio. How would I go about doing this. I already have some code written but I don't know where to go after? I know it has something to do with a for loop. I am using the counts to signify the separate words being split form the array list item.

```
public void setHighScore() {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    lines.add("ryan 150 medium");
    lines.add("andrew 200 medium")
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    while(count < lines.size()) {
        for() {
            if(count2 == 0) {
                count2++;
            }
            else if(count2 == 1) {
                count2++;
            }
            else if(count2 == 2) {
                count2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the output should look like?

Answer (score 4):

use Split();

example:

```
lines.add("ryan 150 medium");
lines.add("andrew 200 medium")

String[] words = lines.get(0).split(" ");
words[0] // ryan
words[1] // 150
words[2] // medium

String[] words2 = lines.get(1).split(" ");
words2[0] // andrew
words2[1] // 200
words2[2] // medium



TextView viewsName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
viewsName.setText(words[0]); // ryan

TextView viewsScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
viewsScore.setText(words[1]); // 150

TextView viewsLevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.level);
viewsLevel.setText(words[2]); // medium
```

Comment: And if i wanted to as soon as they were split load them up to a text view without creating a new array list would there be any way of doing that?

Comment: you want dynamically create textview or just set it to existing textview?

Comment: set it to an existing textview i have created already. I have the id's for each textview as well.

Comment: so, you can just call the view and set it normally.. see edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `foreach` loop of a List and then do any action you need to it.

```
public void setHighScore(){

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    lines.add("ryan 150 medium");
    lines.add("andrew 200 medium");
    lines.forEach(line -> {
        String[] temp = line.split(" ");
        // Whatever you want to do for the line.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setHighScore() {
    List<String[]> listStringArray = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    lines.add("ryan 150 medium");
    lines.add("andrew 200 medium")
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
        String[] words = lines.get(i).split(" ");
        listStringArray.add(words);
    }
}
```

You will get the data in the List of String array.

Now you can set the data to the view like this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(listStringArray.get(i)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more **STANDARD** JAVA approach to solve this problem is to define a `class` which contains the different property. Then use it.

**Person.class**

```
public class Person {

    String name, highscore;
    int points;

    public Person(String name, int points, String highscore) {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
        this.highscore = highscore;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }        
    public String getHighscore() {
        return highscore;
    }    
}
```

Now use this class in your list as follows:

```
List<Person> lines = new ArrayList<>();
lines.add(new Person("ryan", 150, "medium"));
lines.add(new Person("andrew", 200,"medium"));
//Accress them as follows:
lines.get(0).getName(); //this will return ryan
lines.get(1).getPoints(); //this will return 200
```